# How to convert a NetworkX graph with complex weights to a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I have a graph whose weights are complex numbers. `networkx` has a few functions for converting the graph to a matrix of edge weights, however, it doesn't seem to work for complex numbers (though the reverse conversion works fine). It seems to require either `int` or `float` edge weights in order to convert them into a NumPy array/matrix.

```py
Python 3.9.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 29 2021, 19:20:46) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.29.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import networkx as nx

In [3]: X = np.random.normal(size=(5,5)) + 1j*np.random.normal(size=(5,5))

In [4]: X
Out[4]: 
array([[ 1.64351378-0.83369888j, -2.29785353-0.86089473j,
...
...   
         0.50504368-0.67854997j, -0.29049118-0.48822688j,
         0.22752377-1.38491981j]])

In [5]: g = nx.DiGraph(X)

In [6]: for i,j in g.edges(): print(f"{(i,j)}: {g[i][j]['weight']}")
(0, 0): (1.6435137789271903-0.833698877745345j)
...
(4, 4): (0.2275237661137745-1.3849198099771993j)

# So conversion from matrix to nx.DiGraph works just fine.
# But the other way around gives an error.

In [7]: Z = nx.to_numpy_array(g, dtype=np.complex128)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b0b717e5ec8a> in <module>
----> 1 Z = nx.to_numpy_array(g, dtype=np.complex128)

~/miniconda3/envs/coupling/lib/python3.9/site-packages/networkx/convert_matrix.py in to_numpy_array(G, nodelist, dtype, order, multigraph_weight, weight, nonedge)
   1242             for v, d in nbrdict.items():
   1243                 try:
-> 1244                     A[index[u], index[v]] = d.get(weight, 1)
   1245                 except KeyError:
   1246                     # This occurs when there are fewer desired nodes than

TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

I have looked at the documentation and all it seems to say is that this works only for a simple NumPy datatype and for compound types, one should use recarrays. I don't understand recarrays well and using `np.to_numpy_recarray` also yields an error.

```py
In [8]: Z = nx.to_numpy_recarray(g, dtype=np.complex128)
...
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

So the question is how to convert the graph into a matrix of edge weights correctly?

Comment: It should absolutely work the way you first tried. This seems like a bug in networkx. [Here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/3858c531213b88564b3390f34eb9a9c2c0ae5b0d/networkx/convert_matrix.py#L1238) the initialisation is double, which can't be assigned a complex. The type conversion at the end doesn't get a chance before the error.

Comment: I've [opened a PR trying to fix this](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/5245). In the meantime you can at worst copy over the few lines of code [from the implementation](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/3858c531213b88564b3390f34eb9a9c2c0ae5b0d/networkx/convert_matrix.py#L1238-L1246), just pass `dtype=complex` for the `np.full` call. I mean implementing your own `to_numpy_array` until a fix is out in the library.

Comment: Thanks @AndrasDeak for opening the PR and giving a workaround. I'll try and use your implementation, otherwise I'll just work directly with a matrix myself instead of using the networkx object as an intermediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a quick hack that could be useful until a fix is implemented:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np


def to_numpy_complex(G):

    # create an empty array
    N_size = len(G.nodes())
    E = np.empty(shape=(N_size, N_size), dtype=np.complex128)

    for i, j, attr in G.edges(data=True):
        E[i, j] = attr.get("weight")

    return E


X = np.random.normal(size=(5, 5)) + 1j * np.random.normal(size=(5, 5))

g = nx.DiGraph(X)

Y = to_numpy_complex(g)

print(np.allclose(X, Y)) # True
```